# How to select all buttons with forEach in JS dom (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, dom, foreach, addeventlistener

I have 3 buttons having class name "btn";
How can select all button by using addEventListener and forEach?
I don't select one by one
HTML codes:

```
<div class="display">
   <input type="number" class="text">
</div>
<div class="buttons">
   <input type="button" value="1" class="btn">
   <input type="button" value="2" class="btn">
   <input type="button" value="3" class="btn">
</div>
```

JS code:

```
  const display = document.querySelector(".text"),
  btn = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

  btn.addEventListener("click", buttons);

  function buttons() { 
   display.value = btn.value;
   };
```

Comment: Your first button has the class `btn1`, not `btn`.

Comment: this may happened by mistake... how can I apply for each to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the js builtin array function foreach on the buttons selected by querySelectorAll.

I changed the variable names to be unabbreviated, more for my own sake, feel free to change them back.

Basically, you loop over all buttons and add an event handler to each one.

Note: In the event handler assigner function, you will have to use a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), or the function will fire right away.

```
const
    display = document.querySelector(".text"),
    buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener("click", alterDisplayValue(button)));

function alterDisplayValue(button) {
    return function() {
        display.value = button.value;
    }
};
```

You could also use an inline function in the foreach to set the click handler:

```
const
    display = document.querySelector(".text"),
    buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    display.value = button.value;
}));
```

working: https://codepen.io/leonsegal/pen/GGbaZL

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) for this like:

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
for (const btn of btns) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(this.value);
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="1" class="btn">
<input type="button" value="2" class="btn">
<input type="button" value="3" class="btn">
```

For using `forEach()`, you will have to convert `btns` DOM nodes to an array first using `Array.from()` like:

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
Array.from(btns).forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(this.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="button" value="1" class="btn">
<input type="button" value="2" class="btn">
<input type="button" value="3" class="btn">
```

Comment: Wow, this is working. I am curious to know how to do this by forEach loop instead of for...of loop.

Comment: I have shared that logic also. Hope it helps!